# Copy a directory in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, directory, matlab

I'm using matlab 2014a and I need to copy the directory of the files, can you tell me how can i made? thanks

Edit:
I think that you didn't understand my problem, matlab is a simulation program, not a file manager, and the scripts are in X folder, now i can copy the directory by terminal, but i just trying to copy the route.

let me reformulate the question, where can i make Crtl-X or Ctrl-C to copy the directory path?

PD: Please be patient, i'm new in ubuntu

Comment: Is file manager(nautilus) is not enough to copy your directory with all files?

Comment: I think the question here is more about where are the files than how to copy them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your edited question, I guess you want to copy the path of the desired directory

To achieve this, you could `cd` to that directory, then use `pwd` command to Print Working Directory.

Or assign the output to a variable directly, e.g. `CurrentDIR = pwd` as described in the following link.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pwd.html